# Using a ps3 controller for the PC version of Lego Star Wars: The Complete Saga

Tags: pc, controllers, lego-star-wars, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I'm trying to use a SIXAXIS PS3 Controller on my PC for the game, I've downloaded, installed and successfully started the DS3 Tool and configured my controller and all that (Everything works while in the DS3 Tool). When I'm in the game none of the buttons respond to any movements or anything basic like selecting to use the controller at the start of the game.

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work or of what I need to do to get this working if it can?

Comment: Try the different emulation settings in DS3.

Answer (score 1):

XPadder is a software program that acts as a layer translating the controller buttons to actual keyboard keymaps.

http://xpadder.com/

Similar thread: [Can I use a game controller to play Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69000/can-i-use-a-game-controller-to-play-diablo-3)

Comment: If you're using DS3 tool/Motionjoy you can just set your key mappings in there direct, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [XInput Wrapper for DS3 (Dual Shock 3)](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-) as its much cleaner and I found it easier to setup that Xpadder.