# Can I use a game controller to play Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, pc, controllers

**Can I use a game controller with Diablo 3?** Since there are not that many keys that are actually used, can you map a controller to play? Or would this require some type of mod?

Comment: This question needs to be updated. The correct answer might be different now that we know D3 is coming out for PS3 in September 2013.

Comment: OP, do you mind editing your question to ask how you can use a controller without violating any rules? Since we already know it's not supported officially, this seems like a more relevant question to ask. Also you should add `PC` tag to clarify which version of D3 this question is about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not within the game, no you cannot use a game controller to play.  Diablo 3 on PC is intended to be played with Mouse & Keyboard.

Using an external program / mod to add this capability not a good idea, as it is most certainly against the EULA. Using external things to change the game experience is a potentially bannable offense.

Edit many moons later: section 2-2 of the EULA (http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/d3_eula.html) is pretty all-encompassing about what you agreed you will not do:

> Use cheats, automation software (bots), hacks, or any other unauthorized third-party software designed to modify the Game experience, including without limitation, mods that violate the terms of this License Agreement or the Terms of Use;

I would personally categorize a system to use a GamePad without going through the game itself to be something that is "designed to modify the Game experience."

Diablo 3 is now playable on consoles, which obviously use GamePads to great effect, but the game mechanics are subtly different to compensate (for example, on consoles there's a dedicated dodge mechanic). I'm not sure why they never got around to enabling GamePads on the PC version, though.

Comment: I also think the gameplay would probably suck, since the game is heavily based on pointing the mouse cursor where you want your abilities to go.

Comment: Not necessarily. Torchlight worked well on the X360 (for me and people that I know). Blizzard has also expressed their intention to release a console version of the game.

Comment: Guys, game director Jay Wilson says Blizzard devs felt that concerning Diablo III, "the control and style of the game lends itself to a console," adding they had tried a "360-like" controller and "this feels even better with direct control." So please do research before posting opinionated stuff like this. http://www.destructoid.com/blizzard-diablo-iii-with-a-gamepad-feels-even-better--212023.phtml

Comment: There is no reason Diablo III cannot be played with an XBOX360 all you need is a program like XPadder or similar software.  Furthermore its not against the Terms of Service to do so.

Comment: Also: "I can pretty much guarantee that if we decide to do a console version that we will look to support a pad on PC" -Jay Wilson. Although he is the former director, the plan is probably still up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need to remap some of the keys. Good controllers have keymapping or dynamic key binding so you can do it in the game. Otherwise you will have to manually remap the keys in D3 through the options page.

I use a Logitech G13 game pad to play and it makes it so much easier. I especially like 1-click login thanks to dynamic key binding. Highly recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible and here are the reasons:

- Currently it is not possible to use keys (WSAD or controller) for movement. You have to use a mouse.
- Some skills use the cursor as the center of their effect (e.g. Wizard: Blizzard), so you need to position is correctly very fast.
- A controller is not fast enough with this kind of precision, especially in Inferno you will be doomed without a mouse.
- Blizzard follows a strict no third party tool policy, so remapping keys with some kind of application (e.g. xpadder) might get you banned.
- There is no "controller" interface implementation for the inventory and other parts of the game.

Currently the best thing you could hope for is some kind of mouse emulation for your controller.

I am very skeptical that Diablo 3 will ever allow controllers, as the whole UI would need to change and the difficulty has to be reduced.

Comment: Most of these points are 100% false.  Using Xpadder is allowed.

Comment: Well please prove me wrong. I dislike people just claiming something is wrong. I am quite sure that all my points are valid. The answer "No..." might be open to discussion, depending on the limitations you are willing to accept.

Comment: I have used Xpadder since the release of Diablo 3.  Xpadder doesn't do anything that is disallowed in the Terms of Service.

Comment: Won't get you banned since Blizzard is actually working on adding this feature.

Answer (score -2):

I'd grab a USB controller and map 1-4 to ABXY and mouse buttons to trigger buttons. As long as the controller doesn't install any macro software, I can't imagine anyone getting banned for using it. Analog stick sensitivity would be another issue. You'll either be a sloth on the battle field or a Parkinson's victim -- I'd stick with the mouse and keyboard.

Bonus third option: Nostromo game pad?

Comment: The problem is that there is no way to move or case your Left/Right mouse button abilities without clicking. Sure, you could map your buttons such that the controller ABXY buttons do something, but that's not very useful if you can't move or use Left/Right mouse abilities.

Comment: @MagRoader - Have you tried it?  Didn't think so.  Diablo III plays really well on a controller.

Comment: @Ramhound Instead of being snide, please write an answer so we all may learn how to do it properly.